# How can i get all possible ways to traverse a tree

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to build a type that can fin all possible ways to traverse a Tree(object)

for example:

```
interface Tree = {
   a: { b: string, c: boolean },
   d: number
}
```

I want to have a type `NestedObjectKeys` that returns

```
NestedObjectKeys<Tree> ==> [ ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['d'] ]
```

I tried my best, it's difficult for me as a ts beginner

Comment: Didn't understand the logic behind the example?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics), maybe more specifically [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)?

Comment: You are looking for *paths* through the tree, and the linked question's "pre-TS4.1 answer" should do what you want, using the `Leaves` type.